# ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type on applying delete command

Tags: python

```
delRoll=int(input("Enter roll no:"))
    c.execute("Delete from st where roll=?",delRoll)
```

```
import sqlite3
con=sqlite3.Connection("myinfo.db")
c=con.cursor()
c.execute("create table if not exists st(roll int unique,name text,marks int,fee float)")
choice=int(input("1.insert 2:delete 3:update 4:view:"))
if choice==1:
    roll=int(input("Enter roll no:"))
    name=input("Enter name no:")
    marks=int(input("Enter marks:"))
    fee=float(input("Enter fee no:"))
    c.execute("Insert into st values(?,?,?,?)",(roll,name,marks,fee))
    con.commit()
    
elif choice==2:
    delRoll=int(input("Enter roll no:"))
    c.execute("Delete from st where roll=?",delRoll)
    
        
elif choice==4:
    c.execute("select * from st")
    con.commit()
```

Comment: welcome and please check [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), What have you tried already? (Please update the question to show your work)

Answer (score 0):

The extra arguments to a `.execute()` function call should always be a tuple. In the offending command, you supply a single (integer) value instead, which likely gives the error.

Instead, supply a single-element tuple, as follows:

```
c.execute("Delete from st where roll=?", (delRoll,))
```

---

As user56700 remarks, you should also commit your changes after a delete, not only after an insert: any change to the database should be commited. Whereas, in fact, you do not need a commit after a select (since there is no change to the database).

Comment: Ah he's missing commit after the delete. If I add con.commit() after your delete it works.

Comment: @user56700 That as well, indeed. Though that is not causing the titular error message.

Comment: on applying commit after delete ,Same error occur .                              
  and this also not work  --- c.execute("Delete from st where roll=?", (delRoll,))

Comment: @vrishtijain When you say "this also not work": what do you mean for that? You get again the same error, or something else that doesn't work? You need *both* the tuple *and* the commit. Please read my answer carefully: "you should also commit".